# python sum two numbers represented as two arrays

Tags: python

This has two parts. The first part is a sum function and then a multiply function. I'm new to python so struggling with this.

For addition function, I'm trying to do 123 + 52 or 430 + 25 or really any amount of numbers. The numbers are represented as arrays and you cannot convert them into a number. They are automatically reversed, so units are the first element and higher digits are given after.

```
array1 = [3,2,1] (123)
array2 = [2,5] (52)
```

And the same thing for multiply. 123 * 52 or 430 * 51.

So it's really writing an addition or a multiplication as we would do manually, one digit after the other.

So basically how do I write an addition function and a separate multiplication function that does that? I had an earlier function that basically incremented a number represented like that. Ideally, I would like to modify/build on this function:

```
def incrementNum (array)
 for index, digit in list(enumerate(array)):
    if digit == 9:
      array[index] = 0
    else:
      array[index] += 1
      return array
  arrayInt.insert(0, 1)
  return array
```

Comment: What’s the question basically?

Comment: Why does `[3, 2, 1] = 123` and `[2, 5] = 52`? Are they always reversed?

Comment: yes they are always reversed

Comment: Probably the most correct way to get from `[3,2,1]` to `123` is `sum(i*10**p for p, i in enumerate([3,2,1]))`. The multiplication from there should be trivial…

Comment: An alternative would be to go through yucky string concatenation: `int(''.join(map(str, reversed([3,2,1]))))`.

Comment: @deceze I'm not sure how this helps me write a function that takes in two arrays; where that array represents a number, and add or multiply them together

Comment: Well, this code shows you how to turn *one* list into a number. Just replace the `[3,2,1]` with a variable of an equivalent list. You now have a number, which you can assign to a variable. And then you can obviously multiple those two variables together. If you're not sure how to do *that*… well, first of all, tell us that in the question so we are able to explicitly address the point that you don't understand; and secondarily, you may get knowledge better suited for your level from a text book or tutorial than from asking individual questions on SO.

Comment: @deceze I mentioned that you cannot convert the array into number so I don't think it would work

Comment: That is the rather unclear part. Why can you not convert them? Is that an arbitrary restriction? What does it mean that they're "automatically reversed"?

Comment: `[x+y for x,y in itertools.zip_longest(array1,array2,fillvalue=0)]` will do as asked -- but I strongly suspect you want to carry decimals too.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand the question but this is what I would do:

```
from functools import reduce

arr1 = [3,2,1]
arr2 = [2,5]

def sum_func(*args):
    return sum(int(''.join(map(str, reversed(arr)))) for arr in args)

def mult_func(*args):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, [int(''.join(map(str, reversed(arr)))) for arr in args])

print(123 + 52)
print(sum_func(arr1, arr2))

>>>175
>>>175

print(123 * 52)
print(mult_func(arr1, arr2))

>>6396
>>6396
```

Its kinda weird what you're trying to do so the solution might not be that elegant